# How do you do take a time lapse in a crowded city, sit or stand somewhere aside?

Tags: digital, timelapse, video, cityscape

I've never attempted a time lapse in a crowded city, where do I mount myself so I'm not in the way?

Answer (score 3):

There are probably as many solutions to this as there are locations in cities
A brief selection...

1. Indoors. Shoot through a window.
   As noted in comments, this could include a parked car, though there are potential vibration issues.
2. Lash the camera to a lamp-post, tree, pillar, fence, etc - though again beware of transmitted vibration.
3. Elevate yourself - A stairway which isn't currently in use - a bank on a Sunday etc. or a statue plinth might be just sufficiently out of the way that people aren't constantly pushing past you.
4. Immediately inside any cordoned-off area. Looking out from a nearby park or small green space. Though the park may be busy behind you & the street in front, no-one is going to need to be right by the fence.
5. Brave it out. Make your own cordon with cones & tape... this is likely to raise the interest of the local constabulary, so get a permit.

Comment: "*Indoors*" in point 1 can be interpreted broadly to include "*from a parked car*".

Comment: Indeed it could, potential vibration aside. I'll add to the answer, thanks :)